# Moderator close votes

Tags: support, moderation

This [question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2052/what-would-be-a-good-book-by-nagarjuna-for-beginners-to-read) has just been put on hold - i disagree but that's not the question really. I notice that Hrafn put the question on hold with just one vote. I assume that is a moderator superpower. Can the moderators also cast regular close votes as well? Or do their close votes always put a question completely on hold?

I guess what I'm also asking is that if moderators can cast regular votes then I would personally prefer them to do that in most cases - reserving the superpower closing for just really off topic/spam posts - which we have seen. If they can only use a superpower close vote then again I think I would prefer them to wait till at least there seems to be a consensus around a question being closed.

I hope this does come across as a moan. It isn't mean to be - i just wanted to ask the question. I genuinely appreciate the time and care that all 3 moderators all putting into the job. That is appreciated way more than the occasional niggle

Comment: See [the Help Center article on moderators](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) for a full rundown on what mods can and can't do.

Comment: FYI normal voting for moderators has been proposed about 4 years ago on [Meta StackExchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41062/164138). 
Even though the majority of users back then were in favor, the proposal was declined (see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74070/164138) for the reason behind this)

Answer (score 7):

No, when a moderator votes to close a question it does so immediately, without waiting for other votes. Moderators on some sites have asked for the ability to choose (for circumstances where they aren't sure and want to let the site users decide, but this isn't currently a feature of SE.